# New Connection to Realm Object Server Cycles through Notification History

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

*ROS 2.0b-285, Ubuntu 16.04.3, Realm Cocoa 3.0.0-beta 2, Swift 3.1, Xcode 8.3.3, macOS 10.12.6*

**Take a look at this video which demonstrates the issue:** http://d.pr/v/O9GIxF

This Dashboard screen has the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  refreshData()

  //Listen for Realm changes
  let realm = try! Realm()
  notificationToken = realm.addNotificationBlock { notification, realm in
    self.refreshData()
  }
}
```

The `refreshData()` function just has the code that takes the Realm data and updates the UI.

The video shows the app updating to various **historical snapshots** of what the data has been **over time**, until it finally catches up with the **latest** data and stops.

Why does it do this? Why doesn't it just get the latest data and fire the notification block once?

Comment: Are those historical snapshots from changes that weren't synchronised between the local realm and the object server or do you even receive some snapshots that were synced before?

Comment: It's difficult to say for sure, but I'm fairly certain that I'm getting every single change notification since the creation of that realm.

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of `addNotificationBlock` triggers the callback at intermediate historical snapshots, because the realm gets syncronized by transferring history, not state. So, if you want to start getting notifications only about the changes happened after the connection, here is what you should try:

1. Schedule a download-direction callback with [addProgressNotification()](https://realm.io/docs/swift/2.10.0/api/Extensions/SyncSession.html#/s:FE10RealmSwiftCSo14RLMSyncSession23addProgressNotificationFT3forOES_S0_17ProgressDirection4modeOES_S0_12ProgressMode5blockFVES_S0_8ProgressT__GSqCSo28RLMProgressNotificationToken_).
2. Set the notification block as you did originally, but only after the download finishes (callback from 1 fires).